# async function with selenium wait

Tags: python, selenium, async-await, coroutine

I'm building a Selenium Chrome bot using Python. I implement python coroutine a sync function. Using Selenium wait method with python a sync function.

I got an error which behavior is not what I expect.

I select item on drop-down A, wait for few seconds, so that drop-down B will be populated based on item's value in drop-down A.

This process wraps inside python a sync function with await. It doesn't loop according to this behavior.

But run all at once.

**async def**

```
regionLists = ['111','222','333']
regionElem = self.browser.find_element_by_id("regionId")
regionSelect = Select(regionElem)
regionTasks = [
  self.parseCities(self.browser, regionSelect, regionValue)
  for regionValue in regionLists
]

result = await asyncio.wait(regionTasks)
```

**ParseCities function**

```
async def parseCities(self, browser, regionSelect, regionValue):
  regionSelect.select_by_value(regionValue)

  # ERROR AT THIS LINE BELOW
  wait(browser, 10).until(
      lambda b: len(Select(b.find_element_by_id("cityId")).options) > 1
  )
```

**Error**

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<main.parseCities() done, defined at Selenium/main.py:139> exception=NoSuchElementException('Cannot locate option with value: 781111')>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Selenium/main.py", line 140, in parseCities
    regionSelect.select_by_value(regionValue)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/support/select.py", line 87, in select_by_value
    raise NoSuchElementException("Cannot locate option with value: %s" % value)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Cannot locate option with value: 781111
```

Answer (score 3):

*Try to  wait for the element to be clickable*

*Just example*

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

 element = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, 'cityId')))

  element.click()
```